# Get the status of one application from another application

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two applications such as `Activity` and `Service`. I start `Service` from `Activity`. When I exit the activity it stops but it is not completely getting stopped, running in background(Could see in `Settings->ManageApplications` menu).
So I used `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` in `onDestroy`() function which completely terminates application. But the issue is that it also stops my service since it was started from my activity.i also tried using the below lines,

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(this.getApplication().getPackageName());
```

But still it stops my service since it will stop the associate processes as said in document.My question is that how can i terminate my activity completely without killing my service. Thanx in advance.

**Scenario**

---

Assume there are two applications 'a' & 'b'. I stop Application 'a' using `finish()` call, 'a' closes successfully. Now I check the status of 'a' from 'b' using `runningProcessInfo` call and i still find that application 'a' is running in the background.

Comment: you see your application in Setting-> Application->Manage Application under Download Tab or Running Tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is that how can i terminate my activity completely without killing my service.

Call `finish()`, which happens automatically when the user presses BACK (by default).

> When i exit the activity it stops but it is not completely getting stopped, running in background(Could see in Settings->ManageApplications menu)

An application is not an activity. An application is a collection of components. In your case, your application consists of at least one activity and at least one service, based upon the information in your question.

> So i used "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())" in onDestroy() function which completely terminates application.

Do not do this.

Comment: there is a chance that calling finish() method won't result with triggering onDestroy()?

Comment: @TalKanel: `finish()` should lead to `onDestroy()` within milliseconds.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanx for the response. As you i called finish function and it calls onDestroy function. But the thing is that it does not fully stops the my application. i could find it using "RunningAppProcessInfo". it tells that my application is running in background. I dont want my application to be running in background. because i make decision according to the application state later. So how can i stop my application without running in background.

Comment: @GreenHorn: "But the thing is that it does not fully stops the my application" -- it is not supposed to. "I dont want my application to be running in background" -- you said you do in your question, where you complained about your **background service** going away. "So how can i stop my application without running in background" -- you can't, since you want a service to be running. Either the service (and the application it is in) is running, or it is not. Your application cannot be simultaneously running and not running.

Comment: @CommonsWare, the thing is i have 2 applications running. I Stop one application using the aforementioned 'finish' call. From another application i check the status of the previous application using *RunningAppProcessInfo*, But the result that i get is that the previous application is still running in the background. I have updated my question for understandability.

Comment: @GreenHorn: `finish()` does not terminate a process. Android will terminate the process eventually, when it needs the RAM for something else. If "App A" does not have a service, and has no running components after your `finish()` call, it will be terminated in the not-too-distant future, and it is causing no harm to the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare, That was very informative. But its a requirement that i know the status of 'a' (supposedly closed now) from 'b' immediately as i cant wait for it to be closed in the not-so-distant future. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: @GreenHorn: Have App A tell App B "I'm going away now", by sending a command (via `startService()`) or using the `Binder` (retrieved from `bindService()`) to call a method.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks a lot. To resolve this, currently, I'm using sharedPreference method to share a flag variable between the two apps so that i can inform B when A is just about to close. Is this method advisable or should i go along with your method?

Comment: @GreenHorn: App A cannot access App B's preferences, or vice versa, unless you are doing some things that are *not* a good idea (e.g., `android:sharedUserId` or `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`). I strongly recommend using IPC mechanisms, such as sending commands, to communicate between apps, or not have them as separate apps in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ok but what will be the issue in using SharedPreferences.Anyway i am going to use share a flag between two application. Will it make issue using MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

Comment: @GreenHorn: Problem #1 = anyone can read your preferences. Problem #2 = what happens when the user uninstalls the app with the preferences?

Comment: Actually my scenario is that Nothing can be done by reading my flag value which is an integer value.And Ofcourse i should take care of uninstalling case.thanx.